# Need Mechanism to map directory structure to table (or document store)

Tags: python, django, mongodb

- db: mysql
- lang: python
- framework:
- django
- Operating System: Linux (ubuntu)

The current project points I am working has a directory tree structure that will comprise of folders, sub-folders, files.

root path: /var/Testcases

- Folder1

  - subFolder2
  - file1
  - file2
- Folder2

  - subFolder2
  - File1

I can store/map the file paths of the 'file' in a database but I need to know what the directory , subdirectory names are thus I need a mechanism to update the structure every time it has changed.  I've looked at other solutions to 'walk' / crawl and even implemented them but are there any suggestions on how to intelligently store directory structures that will change frequently?  Both Parent folder, sub folder and the name of the file must be stored separately as a column.  Would MongoDB be something to look into ( I'm talking out of my domain)?

I could run a chron job every few seconds to walk the directory and update my table to reflect the changes but there must be some other route. I hope I have provided enough information.  I'm open to exploring various trial and error solutions.  I've heard great things about MongoDB and that's why I threw it out there.

Comment: Depending on the operating system there exist different solutions for hooking into system events and listening for directory changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My OS is linux, asides from event listeners, are there other Databases that facilitate a directory structure rather than storing them as columns in a mysql table?

Comment: perhaps I don't understand your problem are you looking for a way to store the information or a way to determine when the information has changed?

Comment: Both.  I'm looking for tips on storing the directory tree info in such a manner that can later be retrieved, if it changes the changes will be reflected quickly.  For some reason using mysqlDB doesn't seem like an optimal solution to store directory tree structures.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd stick with mysql if your using it for other parts of your project,  relational database is fine for what you want.

Comment: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#hierarchical